# Quick way to nest short-circuited objects?

Tags: javascript

For example, I wish to create an object at the end of a nested chain of objects, eg:

```
window.a.b.c.d = {}
```

But I need to check if the parameters a, b, and c exist, else create them.
As far as I know, you need to do this:

```
window.a = window.a || {};
window.a.b = window.a.b || {};
window.a.b.c = window.a.b.c || {};
window.a.b.c.d = {};
```

Is there a faster/better ("one liner") method?

Comment: There is better if you write a method. If you want a quick and dirty one-liner, you can do a try… catch and see if you have a ReferenceError.

Comment: You can see how many keys the object currently has with `Object.keys(obj).length`

Comment: You can skip writing `window.` from the 2nd statement onwards: `window.a = window.a || {}; a.b = a.b || {}; a.b.c = a.b.c || {}; a.b.c.d = {};`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/383245/2464634

MergeRecursive(window, {a: {b : {c : {d : {}}}}});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lodash's [set](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#set) does exactly this in a one-liner (ignoring import)

```
import { set } from 'lodash'

set(window, 'a.b.c.d', {})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just write the object as below:

```
window.a = {
    b: {
        c: {
            d: {
            }
        }
    }
};
```

But when you want to make this on existent objects, it's better to write a function.

Example:

```
/**
 * Create object(s) in a object.
 * 
 * @param object obj
 * @param array  path
 */
function createObjectPath(obj, path) {

    var currentPath = obj;

    // Iterate objects in path
    for(var i = 0, p; p = path[i]; i++) {

        // Check if doesn't exist the object in current path
        if(typeof currentPath[p] !== 'object') {

            currentPath[p] = {};
        }

        currentPath = currentPath[p];
    }
}
```

And you could use this function so:

```
createObjectPath(window, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
```

The function creates a reference of a argumented object in 1st parameter, then iterate over each string in the array argumented in the 2nd parameter and set each string as a object case doesn't exist in a parent object.

Comment: Not really a "faster" solution though. Very verbose. But thanks.

Comment: There's not other way to do that different without a method. Maybe you want a standard method from `Array.prototype`.

Comment: If there is no other way, then this was the answer I was after :)